# convert untyped python dict() to typed dict of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am from Java background and in Java its possible to serialize/deserialize json into/from Domain model as follows:

```
{
    "id1": {
        "seq001": {
            "curr_seq": "seq001",
            "partition": "2014-05-16",
            "last_send": true
        },
        "seq002": {
            "curr_seq": "seq0012",
            "partition": "2014-05-167",
            "last_send": true
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

Java Json parser can directly deserialize into Domain model as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<String, DatasetEnode>> idToSeqIdToDatasetNodeMap = OM.readValue(..)
```

I want to do something similar in Python as follows:

Domain class:

```
@dataclass(frozen=False)
class DatasetNode:
    curr_seq: str
    partition: str
    last_send: bool
```

first parse Json:

```
raw_map: dict = json.load(json_str) #result is dict[str,dict[str,dict]]
```

Now I want some converter methods as follows:

**1 convert raw dict to dict of dataclass objects:**

```
typed_map: dict[str, dict[str, DatasetNode]] = to_typed(raw_map)
```

**2 convert dict of dataclass object into raw dict**

```
 raw_map: dict = to_raw(typed_map)
```

Is this possible to do this in few lines, rather than write long methods?

Comment: There are no built in ways to do this. There are libraries for facilitating this. `marshmallow`, `pydantic`. a few others I'm sure.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think "typed" is the correct word in this context

Comment: You could use a comprehension. `{i: {k: DatasetNode(**v) for k, v in j.items()} for i, j in raw_map.items()}` but IMO that's less readable than taking a breath and writing a few extra lines.

Comment: I would also suggest libraries like `dataclasses-json` and `dataclass-wizard`. There is also even `dataclass-factory`. A lot of Python libraries already exist for serialization purposes with dataclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been said you should not think in Java terms when working with Python - nothing is "typed" in Python in the sense that you seem to suggest.
Anyhow although there are no built-ins to perform the task you describe, here you have two one-liners that will do the job by a double dictionary comprehension

"Raw" `dict` to "objects" `dict`:

```
objd = {idk: {seqk:DatasetNode(*seqv) for seqk,seqv in rawd[idk].items()} for idk in rawd}
```

"Objects" `dict` to "raw" `dict`:

```
rawd = {idk: {seqk:asdict(seqv) for seqk,seqv in objd[idk].items()} for idk in objd}
```